# Python Regex on String and Storing in Variable

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a Python code that plots charts for multiple csv files. I have a list of the files and I am using a for loop to go through the list and plot. The exact same code is executed for parsing the data and plotting it which is all within the for loop. Here is the structure of my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

files = ['/myhomepath/project1/red/red.csv', '/myhomepath/project1/blue/blue.csv', '/myhomepath/project2/red/red.csv', '/myhomepath/project2/blue/blue.csv'] 

for file in files
    ... #code for parsing and plotting
    ...
    ...
    plt.title('project1_blue')
    plt.savefig("C:/Users/me/Documents/project1_blue.png")
```

So my problem here is quite obvious. Each chart for the different files will have the same title and in the end, there will only be one single image file of the last file in the list due to overwriting. What I would like to do is parse `file`, the current path being used, and extract the last two directory names and place an underscore between them, store it into a variable and use this variable for both the title and the image name. I am thinking a form of regex matching to extract the last two directories of the path "projectX" and "red/blue" however I am not quite sure how to do it. I am fairly new to python (first Python script).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.split` using `/` as a delimiter. Access list from the last using lindex -1, -2, ... like below.

```
import re

files = ['/myhomepath/project1/red/red.csv', '/myhomepath/project1/blue/blue.csv', '/myhomepath/project2/red/red.csv', '/myhomepath/project2/blue/blue.csv'] 

for file in files:

    sp = re.split('/', file)

    title = sp[-3]+'_'+sp[-2]
    name = "C:/Users/me/Documents/" + sp[-3] +'_' + sp[-2] + '.png'

    print(title, name)

# project1_red C:/Users/me/Documents/project1_red.png
# project1_blue C:/Users/me/Documents/project1_blue.png
# project2_red C:/Users/me/Documents/project2_red.png
# project2_blue C:/Users/me/Documents/project2_blue.png
```